# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{\arctan(n)}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I can't use Leibniz since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\arctan(n)} = \frac 2 \pi \ne 0$ (and it seems to diverge anyway, but how can I prove it?)

Comment: Well, there you go. It fails the $n$th term test.

Comment: You almost figured out the answer; the general term does not converge to zero!

Comment: I have proved that the series is not absolutely convergent, but shouldn't I prove that it does not converge conditionally as well? That's what's confusing me.

Comment: @vairë No, you proved it diverged, conditionally as well. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Limit_of_the_summand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a_{n}=(-1)^{n}/\tan^{-1}n$, if it were convergent, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}=0$, and hence $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_{n}|=0$, but you have disproved the last one.

Answer (score 0):

With
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{\arctan n}=\sum_{n\text{ is odd}}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{\arctan n+1}-\dfrac{1}{\arctan n}\right)$$
and using the fact $\arctan n\geq\dfrac{\pi n}{4}$, then
$$\dfrac{1}{\arctan n+1}-\dfrac{1}{\arctan n}=\dfrac{\arctan\dfrac{1}{n^2+n-1}}{\arctan (n+1)\arctan n}\leq\dfrac{\dfrac{\pi}{4}}{\dfrac{\pi}{4}(n+1)\dfrac{\pi}{4}n}\leq\dfrac{4}{\pi}\dfrac{1}{n^2}$$
so the sum will be less than $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: The inequality $\displaystyle \text{arctan}(n) \geq \frac{n\pi}{4}$ is backwards: It should be $ \displaystyle \text{arctan}(n) \leq \frac{n\pi}{4}$ (assuming $n \geq 1$).